# Simulating ionic 1 in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 1 project (I know it is outdated. But cannot really migrate to ionic 2 or 3 due to time constraint) which is working fine on Android.

Now I want to build it for IOS so I build it using `ionic cordova build ios --verbose` and put it in the Xcode and try to run it on Simulator.

But most of the features are not working such as $state.go function from ui-router or templating such as {{variable_here}}.

When I run the project with ionic serve, everything is working fine.

Please help me to figure out what's going wrong with Xcode.

P.S - I'm totally new to XCode and IOS app development. So please forgive me if it is a beginner question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using it in simulator try executing your program into an actual device. I hope this could be of some help.